# opengl reuse texture unit

Tags: opengl, textures

according to the https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Texture, "if two different GLSL samplers have different texture types, but are associated with the same texture image unit, then rendering will fail. Give each sampler a different texture image unit."

but the glactivetexture use enum to iterate texture unit. How to make sure the texture unit is associate with correct target when i want to reuse the unit. for example use unit 2 for 2D first, and then want reuse it for 3D. I have tried glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_1D/2D/3D, 0); but seems not work. Should i use glenable?

Answer (score 1):

You have misinterpreted what this statement on the OpenGL Wiki means.

It is referring to sampler uniforms in GLSL. It is an error to have a `sampler2D` and `samplerCube`, for instance, that both reference the same texture image unit. Since this situation cannot be determined at compile- / link-time, there is no error state that will be generated. Instead, you will create undefined behavior at shader run-time if you try to use two ***different types*** of samplers that refer to the same texture image unit.

Regarding enabling `GL_TEXTURE_1D`, etc. That is for the fixed-function pipeline. It does nothing in shader-based OpenGL, textures are effectively "enabled" or "disabled" completely programatically. If you do not sample anything from a certain texture image unit during the execution of your shader, then you can think of it as "disabled." However, ultimately such thinking is not productive in the programmable pipeline. You should simply forget that those states ever existed.

Comment: but when i try to use GL_TEXTURE_2D and GL_TEXTURE_3D refer to the same texture image unit. and i have two shader program, one of my shader program will use the 1D and the other use the 3D. the render will fail and show black screen. If i use two different texture unit, it will behave correctly. my program is multithreaded, one shader run in the gui thread, another run in another worker thread.

Comment: by the way, I use the gDebugger to debug it and find the same texture unit can bind to both 2D and 3D target, but even the shader program just use 2D, it cannot get the correct value.

Comment: Do you have multiple contexts in order to do this multi-threaded rendering? OpenGL stores texture bindings per-context, texture names (handles) can be shared between contexts, but the underlying state machine (including which textures are bound to what) cannot.

Comment: yes, i have multiple contexts, and use shared context to share those texture

Comment: Are you expecting the texture bound in one context to be bound in the other? You cannot rely on the state machine from one context in another context. So this means if you bind a texture to `GL_TEXTURE0`, for instance, in thread A and then try to draw something using `GL_TEXTURE0` in thread B, thread B will not know anything about what you bound in thread A. They have separate state machines.

Comment: then how should i handle this situation? need use a global value with mutex?

Comment: Bind the texture in the appropriate context, it is that simple. You just cannot expect a texture you bound in one context to be bound in another.

Comment: I did bind texture in the appropriate context,  In thread B I have a shader first bind a 2d to GL_TEXTURE0 and draw sth then in another shader I bound a 3d texture to GL_TEXTURE0 and also draw sth.  it seems the texture unit bind to both 2d and 3d texture , and the texture() function will not work.  Also in other thread, i have a shader use the final texture from the thread B which also bind to texture0. the gdebugger show the texture correctly, but the shader program cannot use them to draw correctly.